# Ruby key value pairs not printing correctly

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to match key value pairs in an array and print them in a clear format:

```
array = [
  {
    'name' => 'Tom',
    'age' => '31',
    'weight' => '180'
  },
  {
    'name' => 'Jane',
    'age' => '24',
    'weight' => '110'
  }
]

array.each do |key, value|
  if #{key} == "name"
    puts "Name_is=#{key}"
  else
    puts "#{key}=#{value}"
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
Name_is={"name"=>"Tom", "age"=>"31", "weight"=>"180"}
{"name"=>"Tom", "age"=>"31", "weight"=>"180"}=
Name_is={"name"=>"Jane", "age"=>"24", "weight"=>"110"}
{"name"=>"Jane", "age"=>"24", "weight"=>"110"}=
```

Expected result is:

```
Name_is=Tom
age=31
weight=180
Name_is=Jane
age=24
weight=110
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: Try `if "#{key}" == "name"`

Comment: Why have you commented out the condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an array of hashes, you need to make a nested loop which loops over the array and, for each hash in the array, loops on the key/value pairs:

```
array.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    if key == "name"
      puts "Name_is=#{key}"
    else
      puts "#{key}=#{value}"
    end
  end
end
```

Also I'm not sure why you have `if #{key} == "name"` while you can simply have `if key == "name"`.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly and I understand it now.

Comment: `if #{key} == "name"` is not equivalent to `if key == "name"`: the `#` starts a comment!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Ruby-like solution:

```
array = [
  {
    'name' => 'Tom',
    'age' => '31',
    'weight' => '180'
  },
  {
    'name' => 'Jane',
    'age' => '24',
    'weight' => '110'
  }
]

array.each do |hash|
  hash['Name_is'] = hash.delete 'name'

  hash.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key}=#{value}"
  end
end
```